# Query for existing rows with composite primary key in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, sql-in

I have a table with a composite primary key.

```
@Entity(
   tableName = "my_table",
   primaryKeys = ["key1", "key2, "key3"]
)
data class MyTable(
   @ColumnInfo(name = "key1")
   val key1: Int,

   @ColumnInfo(name = "key2)
   val key2: Int,

   @ColumnInfo(name = "key3")
   var key3: String,
) { ... }
```

I am fetching new records from a remote datasource, when I get back those records I would like to determine which records are not already in the database based on the composite primary key.

I think with SQL I could have used something like this to determine all already existing rows in the database:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (key1, key2, key3) IN ( (1,2,'foo'), (3,4,'bar') );
```

Current support is back to Android API 24, which means using SQLite 3.9.

However that syntax is not supported in sqlite.  What would be the proper way to query for all existing rows based on the remote list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query works fine in the latest SQLite versions, but since you want to use it with Android, which supports only older versions (at the moment SQLite 3.32.2 in API Level 33), change to a subquery with the `VALUES` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (key1, key2, key3) IN (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,2,'foo'), (3,4,'bar')));
```

For older versions of SQLite use a subquery with `UNION ALL` (tested in version 3.15.1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (key1, key2, key3) IN (
  SELECT 1,2,'foo'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,4,'bar'
);
```

or, with a join that works in any version:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_name t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 1 key1, 2 key2, 'foo' key3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,4,'bar'
) u ON u.key1 = t.key1 AND u.key2 = t.key2 AND u.key3 = t.key3;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/oKaYMtH-).

Comment: This gives an error with comma separator in WHERE clause. " BETWEEN or IN expected, got ','"

Comment: @lostintranslation this works in SQLite 3.26.0: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r6Ua8QWqxYUE5KhFLKH7Rg/0. What is the version of SQLite that you try the code?

Comment: Ah I see, you are assuming Android API 33.  Most devs need to support much older versions of Android than the latest release.  I support back to API 24, so given this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary,  SQLite 3.9

Comment: @lostintranslation check my 2nd query which works in SQLite 3.15.1

Comment: Thanks, that certainly fit the question and the example.  I do however expect to get hundreds or thousands of remote items. At that point building the query becomes fairly cumbersome.  At this point I might just create a new column with a concatenation of the 3 keys.

Comment: @lostintranslation a simple concatenation would not work, because (1, 11, 'foo') and (11, 1, 'foo') both would return '111foo', so you need a delimiter like a `;` (if you are sure that it will not appear in any of the 3 columns). Also, you should create an additional index on the new column. Maybe, a solution with a temp table for the remote items would be better.

Comment: Yup, I created an index, thanks.